# Hibernate returns com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to insert `Member` class as following but it returns below exception.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
Duplicate entry '' for key 'UK_7pn834d04yft1rkvpqf0viuyc'
```

**Code**

```
Member member = new Member(email, encodedPassword,
                    "USER", false, firstName,
                    lastName);

....
session.save(member);
```

**Entities**

```
@Entity
public class Member {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String authority;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String fname;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String lname;
    @OneToMany
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "requester")
    private Set<Friendship> friendRequests = new HashSet<Friendship>();
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "friend")
    private Set<Friendship> friends= new HashSet<Friendship>();
    .....
}



 @Entity
public class Friendship implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -12799066578787745989L;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "username")
    Member requester;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "username")
    Member friend;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    Date date;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    boolean active;

    .....
}
```

Comment: I'm a little surprised this even runs. Your `Friendship` entity appears to have two `@Id` columns both of which are mapped to your join columns. This entity needs it's own primary key.

Comment: @SteveC whats your suggestion then?

Comment: are you using 'username' as ID in your Member Entity?? Its your problem with your entity defining and assigning annotations.

Comment: what's UK_7pn834d04yft1rkvpqf0viuyc? Regarding the two @Id, try to remove one to see how it behaves

Answer (score 3):

Check if you are adding empty string to table that is mapped to `Member`.
Since `Duplicate entry '' for key 'UK_7pn834d04yft1rkvpqf0viuyc'` = you are trying to add the same value second time.

Look at this:
`@Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;`

Since you have marked this as `unique` propably you are trying to add `email` as empty string second time but you have a constraint on it saying you cannot add the same value.

Comment: I checked the values they are not null, I reckon the issue is with one of the collections, although there is no value in those tables.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the keys are generated by Hibernate, e.g. with `hbm2ddl.auto=create`

If this is a development/test environment, you can add @ForeignKey annotations to your model and see which key (related to which property) is being violated after regenerating the tables. It's worth writing a few extra lines for the ease of debugging.

In a production environment, you can track the key from mysql [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/referential-constraints-table.html) tables.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to annotation "requester" and "friend" with "deleted = false, insertable=false".

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to add an entry that already exists in the database( or, at least, it has the same id). You should use an Integer as primary key for next databases. This way you can autogenerate the primary key so you won't have these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the constraints added for hibernate are not matching with the db you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I suspect that using DEFAULT on the position of the id instead of using autoincrement please see this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)